# Clustering and combining points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, clustering

I am trying to cluster points near each other and group them into one coordinate based on the centroid of that cluster based on a bounding box.  I'm able to cluster them and create a group number for the clusters, but I'm having trouble grouping them as one coordinate per cluster.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0.5, minpoints := 2) over () AS cid
FROM locations
WHERE geom 
    @
    ST_MakeEnvelope (
        -114.496858, 33.149466,
        -112.006293, 39.082191, -- bounding box
        4326)
GROUP BY(geom)
```

However, this doesn't seem to group them based on the cluster id (`cid`).  I also need to return  the total of points within that cluster (I looked into `ST_NumGeometries` for this, but can't figure out how to integrate it into the query) and just the lat and lng.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY (cid)`. You're currently grouping by the original `geom`, nothing to do with the clustering. Presumably the original geometries are all distinct, so there'd be as many groups as input features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we wrap your command inside a separate select we can then group by **cid**, and also get the centroid and count of inputs for each 'cluster'.

Here, for my example and given the nature of my data, I have excluded where the points do not sit in a cluster *(WHERE cid IS NOT NULL)*.
*Note : I have changed the bounding box coordinates and eps to suit my sample data.*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS march_grouped_hullpts;
CREATE TABLE march_grouped_hullpts AS
SELECT x.cid, ST_Centroid(ST_COLLECT(x.geom)) geom, ST_NumGeometries(ST_COLLECT(x.geom)) num_points FROM
(
    SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 1, minpoints := 2) over () AS cid, geom
    FROM public.hullpts
    WHERE ST_TRANSFORM(geom,4326)
        @
        ST_MakeEnvelope (
        145.00945, -37.84890,
        145.011165, -37.84674, -- bounding box
        4326)     
    GROUP BY(geom)
) as x
WHERE cid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY x.cid
ORDER BY cid;
```

The second and third images show what is happening in the intermediate steps.
[image: CLUSTER POINTS]

Comment: Instead of `ST_NumGeometries(ST_COLLECT(x.geom))` you can use `COUNT(x.cid)`, to be a little more SQL-like (and it might be slightly more efficient).

Comment: Also looks like `ST_Centroid` is missing?

Comment: Thanks added in the misisng ST_Centroid

Comment: Note that in some cases it might be useful to use a data point as the representative point for each cluster.  This can be done using `ST_PointOnSurface`.